# Maintain ratio between column in CSS grid. How grid-column is calculated?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

I want my grid to maintain a certain ratio, but a long sentence increases the width of the grid it belongs to.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
}

main {
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

aside {
  grid-column: 8 / 13;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Mauris neque quam, fermentum ut nisl vitae, convallis maximus nisl. Sed mattis nunc id lorem euismod placerat. Vivamus porttitor magna enim, ac accumsan tortor cursus at. Phasellus sed ultricies mi non congue ullam corper. Praesent tincidunt sed tellus
    ut rutrum. Sed vitae justo condimentum, porta lectus vitae, ultricies congue gravida diam non fringilla.</p>
</main>
<aside>
  <p>Aside</p>
</aside>
```

I tried using "word-wrap: break-word", "word-break: break-all", "white-space: normal", "overflow-wrap: break-word", "overflow: hidden", but none of them worked.

How do I have the text either wrap within the grid or have the overflow hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a logical behavior and you simply need to understand how the different sizes are calculated and considering you configuration there will be no ratio.

Let's start with an easy example:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
}

main {
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris neque quam, .</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

We have defined a `grid-column:1/8` thus we will implicitely have 7 columns and the size of each one will be calculated based on the content. In this case, it's trivial as we will have the same size of each column. Basically we didn't specify that our grid need to have 7 columns or that they all need to have the same size. This was implicitely defined.

This implicit grid will later be used to place other elements:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
}

main {
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.container > div {
  background:red;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris neque quam, .</p>
  </main>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the red div will be placed on the first column defined previously.

Now let's add another element:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
}

main {
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

aside {
  grid-column: 8 / 13;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris neque quam,</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>A</p>
  </aside>
</div>
```

This is a more complex situation where will have a total number of columns equal to 12 and not all of them are equal size:

[image]

The calculation done here is somehow complex <sup>1</sup> and depends **on the content**. If we refer to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#overview-sizing):

> Once the grid items have been placed, the sizes of the grid tracks (rows and columns) are calculated, **accounting for the sizes of their contents** and/or available space **as specified in the grid definition**.

We did specify nothing in the grid definition so only the content size will decide here. You can clearly notice this if you simply change the content without the need of using long sentences:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
}

main {
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

aside {
  grid-column: 8 / 13;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris neque quam, .</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>A</p>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris neque quam, .</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>ABC</p>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>A</p>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris neque quam  .</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>A Mauris Mauris</p>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>A Mauris Mauris</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>A Mauris Mauris</p>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Each time we used a different content and each time we obtain a different size.

To avoid this you need to **explicitely** define the size of your grid. In your case, you want to have 12 columns with the first item taking 7 and the second one 5. You can simply do like this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:7fr 5fr;
}

main {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

aside {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris neque quam, .</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>A</p>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris neque quam, .</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>ABC</p>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>A</p>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>Mauris neque quam  .</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>A Mauris Mauris</p>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>A Mauris Mauris</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>A Mauris Mauris</p>
  </aside>
</div><div class="container">
  <main>
    <p>A Mauris Mauris A Mauris Mauris A Mauris Mauris A Mauris Mauris A Mauris Mauris A Mauris MaurisA Mauris Mauris A Mauris Mauris A Mauris MaurisA Mauris Mauris A Mauris Mauris A Mauris MaurisA Mauris Mauris A Mauris Mauris A Mauris MaurisA Mauris Mauris A Mauris Mauris A Mauris Mauris</p>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <p>A Mauris Mauris</p>
  </aside>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Let's take an easy example to have an idea how the calculation is done:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width:600px;
}

main {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
main > div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}

aside {
  grid-column: 3/ 4;
}
aside > div {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <div></div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <div></div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

In this example, we have a grid width equal to `600px`, the first element `50px` and the second one `100px` we will have a free space of `450px`. The implicit grid contain 3 columns, so we split this space into 3. One portion will got to the `aside` (`100px + 150px = 250px`) thus we will have a column equal to `250px` containing an element equal to `100px`. The two other portions will go to `main` (`50px + 2*150px = 350px`) thus will have each column equal to `175px`.

[image]

Let's do the opposite. what should be the size of our divs in order to obtain the same column sizes?

Based on the previous calculation the formula is like below:

```
Ca (aside column) = (Dx + F/3)
Cm (main column) = (Dy + 2*F/3)/2
```

`F` is our free space defined by (`W - Dx - Dy`) where `W` is the container width. Now we want to have `Ca = Cm` and after some math stuff we will have.

```
Dx = Dy/2
```

So we simply need to make the first div twice bigger than the second one:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width:600px;
}

main {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
main > div {
  width:calc(2*var(--s));
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}

aside {
  grid-column: 3/ 4;
}
aside > div {
  width:var(--s);
  height:50px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="--s:50px">
  <main >
    <div></div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <div></div>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container" style="--s:100px">
  <main >
    <div></div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <div></div>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container" style="--s:120px">
  <main >
    <div></div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <div></div>
  </aside>
</div>
<div class="container" style="--s:200px">
  <main >
    <div></div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <div></div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

[image]

You can clearly notice that all the grids have the same column size (`200px` in this case) if we respect the relation between both content. Now you can scale this calculaion to your real example and you will better understand.

By the way, you example is a particular case, since you have no free space so the size of the column in `main` will be the size of its content divided by 7 and the one of `aside` will be the size of its content divided by 5.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you for the detailed explanation. I tried calculating my example with the equation and I got Dx = (5/8)Dy, which makes sense to me.  I think the confusing part is when Dx < (5/8)Dy becomes true, or in your case Dx < Dy/2.  My example isn't particular because there is no free space because technically the only way for Dx = Dy/2 to be true, there has to be no space.  It's particular because the free space becomes negative.  I'm assuming the extra space is taken away from Dx and equally distributed to Dy? Truthfully I can't think of a good time to use the grid w/o explicitly defining it

Comment: @Kevvv let's say that the conclusion from all this is that you need to explicitely set the dimension of the grid because if you don't you will have a hard time understanding and calculating the implicit result ;)

Answer (score 1):

I added `grid-template-columns:repeat(13,1fr);`

```css
body {
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(13,1fr);
}

main {
    grid-column: 1 / 8;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

aside {
    grid-column: 8 / 13;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main> 
    <p>Mauris neque quam, fermentum ut nisl vitae, convallis maximus nisl. Sed mattis nunc id lorem euismod placerat. Vivamus porttitor magna enim, ac accumsan tortor cursus at. Phasellus sed ultricies mi non congue ullam corper. Praesent tincidunt sed tellus ut rutrum. Sed vitae justo condimentum, porta lectus vitae, ultricies congue gravida diam non fringilla.</p>
</main>
<aside>
    <p>Aside</p>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using grid because I need a 2 dimensional layout for the website so that I can also control the rowsl.

Comment: This sort of worked.  It kept the text from increasing the width, but also distorted the ratio of grid-column: 1 / 8 and 8 / 13.  Can you explain why the grid-template-columns prevents the text from increasing in the width of the grid?

Comment: It is proportional to 8x 5x ?

Comment: It's proportional to  grid-template-columns:repeat(11, 1fr);